# Оптимизация большого числа коллайдеров

Tags: c#, unity3d, оптимизация

Делаю 2D скролл шутер на юнити.

Есть игрок со своим rigidbodu2d и circlecollider2d и множество пуль с аналогичными компонентами, в rigidbody2d тип Kinematic, все пули триггеры. Пули никак не должны взаимодействовать друг с другом, только с игроком. Перенёс их на разные слои, расставил галочки в матрице слоев.

Всё равно при ~500 пуль на экране начинаются непомерно лаги, хотя если не ставить в пулю коллайдер, то их нет. Профайлер говорит, что почти вся нагрузка идёт из Physics2D.FindNewContacts. Можно ли как-то избавиться от этого поиска или хотя бы уменьшить нагрузку с него? Функция OnTriggerEnter2D есть только в одном из скриптов игрока и нигде больше

Comment: а вам нужны все 500 пуль на экране ?  Может лучше как то оптимизировать этот момент ?

Comment: @Andrey Желательно да, потому что поджанр - буллетхелл

Comment: можете попробовать убрать с пуль коллайдеры. Но добавить  рейкасты от каждой пули. И ими проверять столкновение

Comment: *НЕ ДЕЛАЙ ЭТОГО!* Я тоже пробовал писать буллет хелл на юнити, и встроенная физика юнити совершенно не подходит для этой задачи. Она делает много лишних вещей которые тормозят уже на 300 пульках, а как мы знаем в хорошем таком буллетхелле и до нескольких тысяч может доходить. И это не единственная проблема - если пульки делать геймобжектами, то они тормозят даже без физики. Лучшим решением будет сделать один менеджер всех объектов, свою простую физику, пульки на системах частиц (у меня был вопрос с ответом про них), а от юнити взять только ввод и интерфейс.

Comment: Также, если вам не принципиально делать поддержку WebGL, можете посмотреть готовые ассеты для буллет хеллов, например DanmakU (так вроде назывался)

Comment: Data-oriented подход вам в помощь, сможете хоть тысячу таких проверок делать